# Method not found: System.MissingMethodException Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization

Tags: .net-core, webapi

I am  migrating from .net core  web api from 2.2 to 3.1 I am getting below error at run time .

Soucrec :PII.Enterprise.AspNetCore.ApiStandards

'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AuthorizationServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAuthorization(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection,
System.Action`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationOptions>)'.

I have added settings here

[image]

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddControllers();
         services.AddAuthenticationCore();
      // this line calling third party DLL I am getting exception here 
         services.ConfigureAuthorizationHandler(Configuration);
     }
```

Comment: I have the exact same error but it is within method `ConfigureServices` when calling this: `services.AddOAuth(options =>...`

Comment: @Marijke i am also getting error in ConfigureServices  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.AddControllers();
         services.AddAuthenticationCore();
      // this line calling third party DLL I am getting exception here 
         services.ConfigureAuthorizationHandler(Configuration);
     }